# ListView is overlapped by Elements in Relative view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I have activity in which there is two EditText field, one button and one ListView. I want to show Two EditText Field and button in a rectangle box and below that list. I am not able to acheive this as listview is ovelapped by other as you can see in screenshot. Below is my activity.xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".BalanceActivity_new"
    android:background="#E6E6E6">




        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/testing"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/uan"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter 12 digit UAN Number"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter 10 digit Mobile Number"
        android:layout_below="@id/uan"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


            <Button
        android:layout_width="212dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Show Balance"
        android:id="@+id/show_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/mobile"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </ListView>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add into RelativeLayout

```
android:id="@+id/relative_name"
```

and into your ListView

```
android:layout_below="@+id/relative_name"
```

to move the ListView below your Relative

Comment: It's actually `android:layout_below="@id/relative_name"`, without the **+** sign. You need the **+** only if you are declaring a not yet existing id.